# Using Requests Post to login to this site not working

Tags: python, post, authentication, python-requests

I know there are tons of threads and videos on how to do this, I've gone through them all and am in need of a little advanced guidance.

I am trying to log into this webpage where I have an account so I can send a request to download a report.
First I send the `get` request to the login page, then send the `post` request but when I `print(resp.content)` I get the code back for the login page.  I do get a code[200] but I can't get to the index page.  No matter what page I try to `get` after the post it keeps redirecting me back to the login page

Here are a couple things I'm not sure if I did correctly:

- For the header I just put everything that was listed when I inspected the page
- Not sure if I need to do something with the cookies?

Below is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://myurl.com/login.php'
next_url = 'https://myurl.com/index.php'
username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypw'
headers =      {
    'Host': 'url.myurl.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '127',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Origin': 'https://url.myurl.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://url.myurl.com/login.php?redirect=1',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=3rgtou3h0tpjfts77kuho4nnm3'
                   }
login_payload = {
    'XXX_login_name': username,
    'XXX_login_password': password,
                   }
login_payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_payload)

       r = requests.Session()
       r.get(url, headers = headers)
       r.post(url, headers = headers, data = login_payload)
resp = r.get(next_url, headers = headers)
print(resp.content)
```

Comment: Can you share the actual url? I would be removing the cookie from your headers and let requests set the cookie with the initial request if required

Comment: Here is the actual link `https://eym.sicomasp.com/login.php` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to send separate requests for authorization and file download. You need to send single POST with specifying credentials. Also in most cases you don't need to send headers. In common your code should looks like follow:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url_to_download = "http://some_site/download?id=100500"
response = requests.post(url_to_download, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('your_login', 'your_password'))
with open('C:\\path\\to\\save\\file', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Can you help explain a little further?  When I do this through a browser, First I need to go to the login to the site, then I need to go to another page where I enter data like a date range and format to export a report.  How would that be done in one `post` if i need separate form data for each post?

Comment: I was hoping to create a session that would allow me to login, remember that I am logged in, and allow me to send a request to the page where I export the report.  If I send the request now, all I get is the html code for the login page like it redirected me there.

Comment: I suppose that dates, report format and other related data should be added to your POST as `data`. Something like `data={'date': '17-Jul-16', 'format': 'txt',...}`. You should try to download file manually and check your POST details via developer tools(F12)->Network. Also this data can be specified as parameters in download `URL` like `http://some_site/download?id=100500&date=17-Jul-16&format=txt...`

Comment: I tried this but when performing `print(response.history)` I get a [Response Code 302] (redirect) and doing `print(response.content)` I get the html code to the login screen, so it looks like it's just redirecting me to the login screen.

Comment: Hey I got it! You were right I can just send the `post` request to the url with the login info rather than doing multiple `post` requests.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

There are a few more fields in the form data to post:

```
import requests
data = {"redirect": "1",
        "XXX_login_name": "your_username",
        "XXX_login_password": "your_password",
        "XXX_actionSUBMITLOGIN": "Login",
        "XXX_login_php": "1"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update({"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"})
    r1 = s.get("https://eym.sicomasp.com/login.php")
    s.headers["cookie"] = r1.headers["Set-Cookie"]
    pst = s.post("https://eym.sicomasp.com/login.php", data=data)
    print(pst.history)
```

You may get redirected to index.php automatically after the post, you can check `r1.history` and `r1.content` to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try and view the history to see what I get.  I had tried posting with the additional form data as well but it didn't work.  I think I was messing around with different options and forgot to include those but I have tried it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but I was using Fiddler for debugging and was able to send a `post` request and successfully returned the index page after logging in but I can't recreate in Python.  I think I should get redirected to the index.php but I dont think I'm logging in successfully so it redirects me back to the login.  (I have made sure my username and pw are correct)

Comment: @SenorPenguin, run the edited code and add what .history returns

Comment: I just tried to run the code how you did it and doing a `print(pst.history)` or `print(r1.history)` the only thing returned in the shell is `[]`  Im not sure what that means.  If I do content I still get the html for the login page.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what my problem was, just in case anyone in the future has the same issue.  I am sure different websites have different requirements but in this case the `Cookie:` I was sending in the request header was blocking it.  What I did was grab my cookie in the headers AFTER I logged in.  I updated my headers and then I sent the request.  This is what ended up working:

(also the form data needs to be encoded in HTML)

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

headers = {
    'Host' : 'eym.sicomasp.com',
    'Content-Length' : '62',
    'Origin' : 'https://eym.sicomasp.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer' : 'https://eym.sicomasp.com/login.php?redirect=1',
    'Cookie' : 'PHPSESSID=vdn4er761ash4sb765ud7jakl0; SICOMUSER=31+147234553'  
            }  #Additional cookie information after logging in   ^^^^
data = {
    'XXX_login_name': 'myuser',
    'XXX_login_password': 'mypw',
            }
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    resp = s.post('https://eym.sicomasp.com/index.php', data=data2)
    print(resp.content)
```